# What kind of BMX bike did i find?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image] got this bike for free at a local car repair service. It had been sitting there for a long time.

Comment: All the hall marks of a cheap mass produced bike. No way to identify unless you get lucky around someone recognizing that tube/head set gusset. No intrinsic value.

Comment: As it lies, that's some scrap steel.   If you find some wheels it could be a BMX again.  Other than that there's literally not a lot to go on.  The one-piece crank shows its a low-end bike.

Comment: It's a little better than your average BSO -- I can believe the suggestion that it's a Mongoose.  But it's not really worth anything, unless you want to built it up as a hobby.

Answer (score 1):

That bike frame is a **Mongoose**.

My parents bought one for me at Christmas in the late 70's.  It was known and very popular for the rims it came with, which were called "moto-mags"

[image: From Google Image search, via pinterest. https://i.pinimg.com/736x/f1/c6/9a/f1c69a1b3ba9a33a18e8cc58243afc75--bmx-bikes-mongoose-bmx.jpg]

Comment: Excellent answer - I've edited in an image that has the same gusset behind the head tube.  If its not what you meant, feel free to change it with the Edit link.  I notice this one has a different crank and chainring, and the fork appears much skinnier than OP's one.